# multiple js dom event is not working on google dev console

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome, dom

I'm a new learner and I'm trying to fill Aliexpress Shipment address, below is my code that I'm using to fill the form. I'm using this following code in GOOGLE DEV CONSOLE. I paste the code in console and hit enter.

```
document.getElementById('contactPerson').select();
document.execCommand('insertText', false, "haider");

document.getElementById('zip').select();
document.execCommand('insertText', false, "56567");
```

the code only fill the form but when i press the save button on aliexpress to save the changes its only saves the zip code changes, the contactPerson changes not saved.
but if i use below code:

```
document.getElementById('zip').select();
document.execCommand('insertText', false, "56567");

document.getElementById('contactPerson').select();
document.execCommand('insertText', false, "haider");
```

this will save changes of the only contact person and zip code changes will not save. I don't know what is wrong with this google dev console. I thinking it only executing the last code only.

please my problem is that why multiple dom js cannot be performed

Comment: i tried you code on aliexpress register user page for email and password and its works!

Comment: no man you taking it wrong i'm talking about the shipping address when you go in my aliexpress